# SQL: Minimising rows in subqueries/partitioning

Tags: sql, sql-server

So here's an odd thing. I have limited SQL access to a database - the most relevant restriction here being that if I create a query, a maximum of 10,000 rows is returned.

Anyway, I've been trying to have a query return individual case details, but only at busy times - say when 50+ cases are attended to in an hour. So, I inserted the following line:

```
COUNT(CaseNo) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(hh, 
         DATEDIFF(hh, 0, StartDate), 0)) AS CasesInHour
```

... And then used this as a subquery, selecting only those cases `where CasesInHour >= 50`

However, it turns out that the 10,000 rows limit affects the partitioning - when I tried to run over a longer period nothing came up, as it was counting the cases in any given hour from only a (fairly random) much smaller selection.

Can anyone think of a way to get around this limit? The final total returned will be much lower than 10,000 rows, but it will be looking at far more than 10,000 as a starting point.

Comment: It definitely works! If I run it over a short period it returns only the busy hours. If I run it over a longer period it returns nothing because it's only getting a selection of cases from any given hour, so that no hour appears busy.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really MySQL we're talking about, `sql_big_selects` and `max_join_size` affects the number of rows examined, not the number of rows "returned". So, you'll need to reduce the number of rows examined by being more selective and using proper indexes.

For example, the following query may be examining over 10,000 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM stats
```

To limit the selectivity, you might want to grab only the rows from the last 30 days:

```
SELECT * FROM stats
WHERE created > DATESUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

However, this only reduces the number of rows examined if there is an index on the `created` column and the cardinality of the index is sufficient to reduce the rows examined.

Comment: Ohh, I thought StackExchange had instant email! I'm now away from work for a week and a half, sorry :/. If I'm right from here, this would be about limiting the number of cases examined in the first case to only those in period? Problem is it's already doing that - it's just that the number of cases in period is well over 10,000. It can deal with this straight from the tables, but apparently not from within the subquery. Hm, perhaps if it's inserted into a temporary table it'll be okay, but I guess I'll have to wait for a bit now.